# Why would XMLHttpRequest suddenly stop working?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have locally recreated an embedded-script example from the W3Schools site, but it does not work properly. It executes, creating the expected HTML page, but the onclick-activated XHR function does *not* alter the innerHTML content as expected. Here is the original code from the relevant page (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_httprequest):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried several things:

1. I created a local text file with the same name as the one being opened in the sample script, and put it in the same directory. Page loaded with button, nothing happened when it was clicked.
2. I added "tracers" to the script in the form of alerts to confirm the script's progression:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  alert("main function successfully called");
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert("onreadystatechange function successfully called");
    alert("readyState: " + this.readyState + " " + "status: " + this.status);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      alert("readyState/status function successfully called");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

When executed, the first two alerts appeared as expected. The third appeared twice, reflecting a change in readyState from 1 to 4, but the status remained 0 in both alerts. The fourth "tracer" alert never appeared.

3. I altered the final conditional to allow for "status == 0", and the fourth alert appeared, and the button disappeared...replaced by nothing.
4. Just to be sure, I changed it so that the string "hello world" was directly added to the innerHTML, which worked.
5. I tried the same variants on a different workstation (both were running Ubuntu Linux btw, and I executed the code with both Firefox *and* Chromium).

Obviously, the responseText is coming up empty. And presumably this is because the request failed, as evidenced by the status remaining 0 instead of changing to 200.

It would be bad enough if I couldn't get this simple code to work, but here's the hair-tearing, teeth-gnashing part: I ran this *same* code sample a couple of days before, and it executed *flawlessly*. Furthermore, I had written a much more complicated script employing my new-found knowledge of xhr to load *much* larger files, store their contents in variables and perform .searchs on them, *also* without any problems. I was in the process of elaborating the code when it failed, and at first I thought I'd made a change that "broke" it. But as I rolled it back to more and more "primitive" versions - versions I *knew* had worked - I discovered xhr no longer worked at all, as corroborated by formerly executable tutorial code no longer working, either.

I don't remember if there was an interim update of Firefox or Chromium that might have affected things, but that seems like a pretty weak possibility.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: The issue is with this.responseText.  Try using the argument to the ajax return function, rather than this, eg  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(data){alert(data)}

Comment: `'xmlhttp_info.txt'` is a relative URL pointing to a file on your Server. If it's not there it won't work.

Comment: can you show an example of the value of `this.responseText`

Comment: In response to StackSlave: I appreciate you taking the trouble to chime in, but in item #1 of the things I tried, I already mentioned that I created a file to match the filename being opened.

Comment: To Jaromanda X: Unfortunately I can't, unless you notice that I mentioned the original innerHTML content of the <button> disappearing. Which implies that the .innerHTML method actually worked, but since nothing was returned with .responseText, nothing was put in the original content's place.

Comment: To Programnik: Yup, I thought of that, too. I neglected to mention it because my "tracer" alert results show the expected readyState change to 4, which wouldn't happen if "this.readyState" - or "this.status" or "this.responseText", for that matter - wasn't working. But for the record, I did try "xhttp" instead of "this", with the same results. And let me repeat: this code actually worked for me when I first tried it a couple of days ago. I suspect something "under the (browser's) hood" has changed, but I don't know enough to figure out what it might be.

Comment: @rccapps: Your example at the top of the page works perfectly for me. I put the textfile into the same folder as the webpage.

Comment: @rccapps: FWIW, I'm on arch linux 5.2.0-arch2-1-ARCH, chrome 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit), and I used the node http-server to run the project.